# Condition on event type in jquery

Tags: jquery

can we set condition on event type like if event is `click` then alert 'clicked' if event if `mouseover` then alert 'over'. but my function is alerting value when function is loading on the page

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

    if($('.wait').click()) {
        alert('click')
    }
    else if ($('.wait').mouseenter()) {
        alert('mouseenter')
    }
})
</script>

<style>
    .wait {color:#F00}
    .nowait {color:#00F}
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wait">abc.....</div>
    <div class="wait">abc.....</div>
    <div class="wait">abc.....</div>

</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
(document).ready(function() {
   $('.wait').bind('click dblclick mousedown mouseenter mouseleave',
               function(e){
               alert('Current Event is: ' + e.type);
                    });
                   });
```

Comment: this is to catch any event you want and alert it

Answer (score 3):

The idea in this case is to define different handlers to different event types :

```
   $('.wait').click(function(){
        alert('click')
    });
   $('.wait').mouseenter(function(){
        alert('mouseenter')
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is wrong, use instead:

```
$(".wait")
.click(function(event) {
    alert("click");
    // do want you want with event (or without)
})
.mouseenter(function(event) {
    alert("mouseenter");
    // do want you want with event (or without)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try simply

```
   $('.wait').click(function(){
        alert('click')
    });
```

and

```
   $('.wait').mouseenter(function(){
        alert('mouseenter')
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Write up separate events to handle them..

```
$('.wait').on('click',function(){
        alert('Click Event !!');
    });

   $('.wait').on('mouseenter'f,unction(){
        alert('MouseEnter Event !!')
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're binding multiple event handlers to the same objects, I would personally pass an event map (an object) to the `.on()` function, like so:

```
$('.wait').on({
    click: function(e) {
        alert('click');
        // handle click
    },
    mouseover: function(e) {
        alert('mouseover');
        // handle mouseover
    }
});
```

However, if *all* you wanted to do was output the event type, there's an easier way to do that:

```
$('.wait').on('click mouseover', function(e) {
    alert(e.type);
});
```